# Does a water softener add sodium to your drinking water?

Tags: water

We have just moved house and the new home has a water softener which I've been pouring salt into. Does this salt end up in the water and will it raise the sodium content of the water? I'm concerned that the children might be getting too much sodium from this water softening system.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm going to have to close this.  This does not relate directly to parenting.  Please review our [faq].

Comment: @Beofett - Perhaps it would be better to move to diy.so, instead of outright closing it?

Comment: @Shauna It doesn't strike me as anything related to DIY, either (I believe that would fall more into "how do I install my own water softener" category), but I will ask the mods there if this is something they'd be interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does add sodium, but not much. According to Mayo, it's negligible but if you are concerned, talk to your doctor:

http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/sodium/AN00317

Comment: To add - the salt in a water softening system is only used during the regeneration/recharge cycle, in which the salt is used to flush out the other minerals in the system and not directly used in the water we use. See: http://homerepair.about.com/od/plumbingrepair/ss/water_softener_7.htm